# CentOS 7 Generic Cloud login?

Tags: centos7, cloud-computing

I have an OpenStack cloud and added the CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1503 image and it boots just fine, but I do not know how to login. What is the root password? How can I set it? Is there some other account I need to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default username for the CentOS 7 cloud image is `centos`. There is no password; instead you log in with the ssh key you provided at instance creation. You can then sudo and do whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks I was going to resort to guestfish https://access.redhat.com/discussions/664843 but your answer is the correct way to deal with logins to cloud images :)

Answer (score 4):

If you downladed the GenericCloud image from cloud.centos.org, it does not have any users created. You can change the root password using virt-customize from libguestfs-tools package:

```
# virt-customize -a image_name.qcow2 --root-password password:your.great.password
```

Just keep in mid that this is not secure. After you login as root, you should create a sudo user, set up key-based authentication for ssh, disable root login, etc.

Comment: Hi, I have tried both ways as mentioned with username centos and no password and changed password with virt-customize but still, I am unable to login to the instance created in  OpenStack. I am using CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2 image. Any suggestion?